# Seqeulize association error: A is not associated to B m:n association

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i have a the following sequelize models:

```
class Technician extends Model {
        static TABLE_NAME = "Technicians";
        static MODEL_NAME = "Technician";
    static associate({ BSAprovider, TechniciansBsaProvider }) {
            Technician.belongsToMany(BSAprovider, {
                through: TechniciansBsaProvider,
                foreignKey: 'technicianId',
            })
        }
    }
}
```

AND

```
class TechniciansBsaProvider extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
        TechniciansBsaProvider.hasOne(models.Technician, {
            foreignKey: 'technicianId',
            targetKey: 'id'
        });

        TechniciansBsaProvider.hasOne(models.BSAprovider, {
            foreignKey: 'providerId',
            targetKey: 'id'
        });
    }
}
```

AND

```
class TechniciansBsaProvider extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            TechniciansBsaProvider.hasOne(models.Technician, {
                foreignKey: 'technicianId',
                targetKey: 'id'
            });
    
            TechniciansBsaProvider.hasOne(models.BSAprovider, {
                foreignKey: 'providerId',
                targetKey: 'id'
            });
        }
}
```

when i try to eager load:

```
    const technician = await Technician.findByPk(techId, {
        include: [BsaProviders]

    });
```

for some reason i am getting an EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: BSAprovider is not associated to Technician!

can anyone explain why? i have tried solving this for hours.

Comment: Make sure all `associate` model methods were called prior to any usage of model and also `associations` prop of the main model of the query (`Technician`) if it has the association with `BsaProviders`